# How to enable DNS Load Balancing in a Docker Compose YAML file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple docker-compose.yaml file with 2 ElasticSearch services:

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: elasticsearch:6.5.4
    restart: always  

  elasticsearch2:
    image: elasticsearch:6.5.4
    restart: always
```

I want to enable DNS Load Balancing for them in the compose file, but I did not find a way to do this. I know that with `docker run` this is possible using `--net-alias`. What's the equivalent in Docker Compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same functionality is there in a compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: elasticsearch:6.5.4
    restart: always
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch2:
    image: elasticsearch:6.5.4
    restart: always
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - elasticsearch
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases